# resolved does not use my DNS server

Tags: systemd-resolved

Ubuntu 20.10
In my local network I have my DNS server (IP hole)
addres of this server is 192.168.0.155
Until systemd-resolved.service is active my system do not use this server
When resolved is disable and I will edit /etc/resolv.conf and put dns server IP addres
All is working fine (until next reboot)
Where to look for a problem ??
resolvectl status   -- give me right ip addres of my DNS
Best regards

Comment: How are you testing this?  More and more services and applications are moving to DoH and similar DNS resolution methods that are more secure and private. Firefox is probably the most significant one to recently switch to using DoH for DNS resolution.

Comment: Firefox is currently hosting an open comment period about the worldwide rollout of DoH.  Perhaps you can add your voice to let them know that you would still like a DNS based method for content blocking. Personally, I've suggested mozilla to work with the pihole team to make this a reality.  See: https://blog.mozilla.org/netpolicy/2020/11/18/doh-comment-period-2020/

Comment: 'sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf' and reboot should preserve your edits

Comment: OK. It looks like chattr have "done the job". I am really happy with pihole so for now it need to be like that. Thanks for Your time and help to all of You.
To someone who has the same problem.
Poblem was with resolved
To switch off resolver>
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo system stop systemd-resolved.service
and at the end 
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf   --put your dns ip
sudo chattr +i  /etc/resolv.conf
Solution is not perfect but it works (for now )